# User uploaded images on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Say you are creating a facebook style app for the app engine.  How would you handle user profile pics?

As far as I know, you would have to either store the images in the datastore or blobstore.  Which means every fetch to a picture would require going through a dynamic handler and using up at least 20ms cputime.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Or is this just something the app engine can't currently handle?

Comment: Is using 20ms CPU time per request a big issue? That works out to $0.0006 - six ten thousandths of a cent - per thousand requests.

Comment: @nick Say you put a thumbnail of their pic next to every status update they have.  Then on your home page where you see your friend's updates, you see 20 different thumbnails.  That means every page view requires 20 roundtrips to the datastore or memcache... And the 20ms cpu time was a best case scenario, average would be much higher (http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2010/07/27#ae-trust-detail-datastore-get-latency).  20 datastore round-trips per page view just seems off...

Comment: The first pageview will require 20 roundtrips - but you should be sending caching headers so users' browsers will cache the thumbnails. If you use the blobstore, too, there's no datastore roundtrip required. Besides, you should be at least as concerned about the impact on user experience and latency imposed by adding 20 extra images to each page than you are about the billing impact on the server end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have this issue anymore, since [get_serving_url()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html#Image_get_serving_url) doesn't use any of your CPU quota (only outgoing bandwidth and storage).  Plus it gives you scaling and cropping for free.

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare a few different options:

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html#Billable_Quota_Unit_Cost):

- $0.10 per CPU hour
- $0.12 per gigabyte outgoing bandwidth

[Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/overview.html#pricing):

- $0.01 per 10,000 GET requests
- $0.15 per gigabyte downloaded for Americas and EMEA

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

- $0.01 per 10,000 GET requests
- $0.15 per gigabyte up to 10 TB / month data transfer out

Say you're serving 10 million images at 50KB each.

On App Engine, with a dynamic handler using 20ms per request, this is going to cost you $57.22 in outgoing bandwidth plus $5.55 in CPU time. On Google Storage or S3, you'll pay $71.52 for the outgoing bandwidth plus $10 for the GETs.

So basically if your handler uses less than 36ms CPU time, it's cheaper on App Engine than on services designed for this exact purpose. Somebody double-check my math, please. =)

Answer (score 0):

And cache the most recently used images in the memcache. That's pretty much all the platform affords.

GAE is a good tool for the class of applications it was built for. Making a Flickr clone is outside its design intentions.